# On using support libraries in Android for graphical reasons

Tags: android, android-support-library

I feel I have some questions about using support libraries. Having started developing some months ago, I am facing the situation where all of my targeted devices (let's say API>16) have pretty good and consistent tools, smart enough to fit my needs, but really miss some UI elements in comparison with API=21.

Today I added three new dependencies from the v7 support libraries. What I've noticed is that, as expected, the app size lifted from just 200kB to 3800kB. While that does not really make me worried, I can imagine that, along with size increasing, the smoothness of a process relying on dependencies can be reduced. And I went for v7 for purely graphical wishes.

I'm wondering: is it convenient to rely on support libraries if not strictly needed? Is it reasonable to add size and lose some smoothness, just to bring Material to, say, >4.2 users? Would it be better to have separate styles and take some (sometimes hard) work to emulate new features on older OS versions?
(note that the goal here is maximizing the popularity of the app).

As a consumer myself, I'd go for the best looking UI, but only if the app runs as it should. In addition, the older the device (and we're talking about older devices here), the more concerned should the user be about size and smoothness, as his hardware would be dated.

*P.S.*: I don't think that 4MB is a troubling size - I'm asking for some kind of "rule". Plus, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and I feel my question could be "constructive", although secondary. Feel free to flag it if it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any library is a shortcut to doing all the work yourself - if you find it more efficient to pour over the design guidelines, implement , and test on many devices and many API versions, then do so. For many, the easier choice is to use the Support Library.

For APK size and 'smoothness of a process', Google provides two tools minification (via [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)) and resource shrinking as per [this Google+ post announcing their availability](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+TorNorbye/posts/eHsStybrrBf). Assuming you are using Android Studio and Gradle, you can add:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}﻿
```

Which will strip out unused methods (the `minifyEnabled` part) as well as unused resources (the `shrinkResources` part). This can be especially helpful with libraries such as the AppCompat Support Library which contains a number of image resources that you may not actually use in your application.

Obviously, the minification/shrinking process takes some time and can slow down your development process hence why they are only enabled in that example for release builds.

Comment: I didn't know about those tools, I will definitely check them out. Thank you, hope this can be useful to others. I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using the support libraries. We use them on our commercial app and we do not get complaints from users with older devices. But because we use them we are able to move very quickly to adopt new Android features, many of which would be extremely difficult to implement ourselves. Especially with Lollipop, Google is making it harder to just imitate the UI.

I was going to add some comments about ProGuard, which I also recommend, but Ian's answer has some great suggestions along those lines, so I will leave it at that.